# ROS Groovy Installation on OSX fails - rviz and OGRE

Tags: ogre, ros

When trying to install ROS Groovy in mac osx, following http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source tutorial, I get

> [ 60%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_widget_geometry_change_detector.cxx.o
>   Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_selection_panel.cxx.o
>   [ 61%] Building CXX object src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/moc_tool_properties_panel.cxx.o
>   Linking CXX shared library /Users/mllofriu/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rviz/lib/librviz.dylib
>   ld: library not found for -lOgreMain
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   make[2]: *** [/Users/mllofriu/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rviz/lib/librviz.dylib] Error 1
>   make[1]:**  [src/rviz/CMakeFiles/rviz.dir/all] Error 2
>   make: ** [all] Error 2
>
> <== Failed to process package 'rviz': 
>     Command '/opt/ros/groovy/env_cached.sh make -j4' returned non-zero exit status 2
>   Command failed, exiting.

OgreMain seems to be inexistent in OSX. What can I do to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Ogre is a 3D rendering engine and not part of OSX (but supported on that platform). The ROS project uses Ogre for the rendering part in their visualization tools.

According to their website, there currently is an issue with the ROS+Ogre build process, that they are working on, compare this [ROS support ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5595).

In the meantime, you should try the two other build options listed [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source#groovy.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-Source.Building_the_catkin_Packages) until they managed to sort out their build process issues:

**Desktop Install (recommended):** ROS, rqt, rviz, and robot-generic libraries 
**ROS-Comm: (Bare Bones)** ROS package, build, and communication libraries. No GUI tools.

Another option might be to compile Ogre yourself, if you feel up to the task.